# Get list of indeces of list satisfying a condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the form:
`[True, False, True, True, False, True]`
Is there an effective way of getting the list of indeces which are `True` (i.e. `[0, 2, 3, 5]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest solution

```
 [i for (i,  e) in enumerate(mylist) if e]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [True, False, True, True, False, True]
>>> l2 = [i for i,x in enumerate(l) if x]
>>> l2
[0, 2, 3, 5]
```

what `enumerate` does is create an iterator with yields a tuple like `indexofitem,item` then the list comprehension only adds an item if `x` is true